# Facebook Chatbot attachments array

Tags: facebook, messenger, facebook-messenger, chatbot

I made a ChatBot for Facebook Messenger: https://www.facebook.com/NEXMO-Inmuebles-Real-Estate-1749955108573136/; you can try it sending this code: EkEcPvJM-

Also you can create a new ad sending a long descritption; after that you can send some images to be attached to the ad. Until the last week all work fine; but this week; when I try to upload multiple images; Facebook only send 1 image in the webhook call. The attachment field is and array, but now always come with 1 element.

Here is the Json request to the webhook:

```
messaging_events: [{"sender":{"id":"992595760822845"},"recipient":{"id":"1749955108573136"},"timestamp":1463773851626,"message":{"mid":"mid.1463773851542:a544a521c42088c878","seq":7849,"attachments":[{"type":"image","payload":{"url":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/13245976_10210276663850947_111702875_n.jpg?oh=a0d71d89bd74a601d4b28db37c0e7814&oe=5741DB9B"}}]}}]
```

Any idea what's happend ?? Is there any contact with facebook suppor team?

Thanks.-

Comment: See if current bug reports have anything similar, and if not file a new one: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs